# How do I select a value from a nested JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JS array:

```
var Boletins = [{
    id: 1,
    items: [{
        "#": "1",
        "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
        "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
        "Niveis": "muito elevados",
        "PoleneArvore": "cipreste, pinheiro",
        "PoleneErva": "urtiga, gramíneas"
    }, (...)]
}, (...)];
```

It goes until `id: 14`. My question is, how do I select, for example, the field `Data` from a certain id? Thanks in advance to those who help!

Comment: Hello, did you have a look at the [array documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to see if some method could help you do what you want?

Comment: *"a certain id"*: please make this concrete, on a concrete example (without the `(...)`), and add the code you have been trying with so far. Hint: you'll have to loop over the array.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to put all data or some data to make sense how your data looks like. Do you need all the data fields which are inside item array of any id element or just one.  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, a solution to your question may be as follows:

```
const data = Boletins.filter(x => x.id === 1).flatMap(data => data.items);

data.forEach(x => {
  console.log(x["Data"]);
});
```

Comment: That's it! Just a last question, what do I have to change in order for it log on console just once per id?

Comment: I would have to better understand how the data is composed as I don't really understand the question